# Colorbox inline HTML not loading correctly

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a very simple question (I think). I am using Colorbox on my 'about' link here:
http://www.zsigmonda.com
As you can see, the inline box isn't sizing correctly - the transition isn't smooth. It jumps from a large box to a smaller one without the elastic transition. 
Could someone please help me figure out what I've done wrong?

Any help would be SO appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**demo:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/jquery-colorbox-background-transition-effect

You can play with the `transition` and `speed` option colorbox provide to create a smoother transition effect. Check the settings section in their home page http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox Like this

```
$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%",transition:'elastic',speed:600});
```

change the `speed` param up and down to make the transition better.